# How can I disable selected text moving by mouse press in TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I need to create a `TextBox` that only accept numbers between `1` and `60`. My problem is the user can drag the selected text and move. This can create incorrect result.

Here is a gif that show the problem:

[image]

Can someone say a method which I can use to disable this functionality.

Comment: Also don't forger about copy-paste. You should add validation. For example handle something like `OnValueChanged`

Comment: You can't disable the drag, but you can disable the drop by setting AllowDrop = false on the textbox.  Of course, that will disable ALL drops.

Comment: Sorry wasn't paying attention to the tags disregard last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say textbox, but even your gif shows a numeric up down.  Using a numeric up down, you can set a max and min which will cap at max once it loses focus, such as clicking a button.  Therefore, any functionality you want to use the numeric up down value for will update the value first, then run the rest of the program.  If you want to completely prevent the drop all together, you can set AllowDrop to false.